# Change the value of another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for Excel-Vba code to  directly show a certain text in a certain cell  based on the value of another cell ,let me elaborate . The table will be as follows:

1. I will input the grades in column A say from cells A3:A13
2. The code must print the corresponding comment on its own ,like if a1 - excellent if a2 - good work
3. This code must work for an entry of range of say 40 grade entries

```
Grades  ------          Comments
a1      ------          excellent 
b2      ------          work harder
a1      ------          excellent
b1      ------          satisfactory
a2      ------          good work
```

Comment: In this case, I will suggest you to use VLOOKUP. Maintain Grades and Comments in One sheet and Input your Grades in another sheet and comments related to your grade will get populated automatically using VLOOKUP formula.

Comment: paresh j - VLOOKUP , doesnt work in this case i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code continues until it finds a student in column A which has not been graded:

```
Sub gradeComments()

    Dim grade As String, comment As String
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 3 ' your starting row

    Do While i > 0

      grade = Range("A" & i).Value

      If grade = "a1" Then
         comment = "Excellent"
      ElseIf grade = "a2" Then
         comment = "Good work"
      ElseIf grade = "b1" Then
         comment = "Satisfactory"
      ElseIf grade = "b2" Then
         comment = "Work harder"
      End If

      If grade = vbNullString Then
        Exit Do
      Else
        Range("B" & i) = comment
        i = i + 1
      End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: but when i am executing this code ,it some how leaves the comment for the first grade !! Thanks @Miqi180

Comment: If the first entry is in cell A3, it works as it should by me. Otherwise, Just set i = your starting row (probably 2).